# "kubeadm-config" in the kube-system namespace used for getting configuration information was not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have a Kubernetes cluster created by Kubeadm.

My current version of the cluster is v1.19.2 and trying to upgrade to v1.20.15-0

Now I am trying to upgrade the kubeadm cluster via `kubeadm upgrade plan` but I got below error :

```
[upgrade/config] FATAL: the ConfigMap "kubeadm-config" in the kube-system namespace used for getting configuration information was not found
```

But when I check the config map `kubeadm-config` in the kube-system namespace. it's seem there.

```
 [root@AWL-MV-IBO-DEV ~]# kubectl get configmap kubeadm-config -n kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ClusterConfiguration: |
    apiServer:
      extraArgs:
        authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
      timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
    apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
    certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
    clusterName: kubernetes
    controllerManager: {}
    dns:
      type: CoreDNS
    etcd:
      local:
        dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
    imageRepository: k8s.gcr.io
    kind: ClusterConfiguration
    kubernetesVersion: v1.19.2
    networking:
      dnsDomain: cluster.local
      podSubnet: 192.168.0.0/16
      serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
    scheduler: {}
  ClusterStatus: |
    apiEndpoints:
      awl-mv-ibo-dev:
        advertiseAddress: 10.20.20.214
        bindPort: 6443
    apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
    kind: ClusterStatus
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-10-06T13:09:22Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        .: {}
        f:ClusterConfiguration: {}
        f:ClusterStatus: {}
    manager: kubeadm
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-10-06T13:09:22Z"
  name: kubeadm-config
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "162"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config
  uid: a6856541-6e6b-4c7e-9163-05778ef5e1aa
```

Anyone can advise why it cannot find the config map?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, according to this [thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2274) in github.

> A bug was discovered in the `enforceRequirements` func for upgrade
> plan. If a command line argument that specifies the target Kubernetes
> version is supplied, the returned `ClusterConfiguration` by
> `enforceRequirements` will have its `KubernetesVersion` field set to
> the new version.
>
> If no version was specified, the returned `KubernetesVersion` points to
> the currently installed one.
>
> The only option is to make `enforceRequirements` consistent in the
> upgrade plan case and always return the currently installed version in
> the `KubernetesVersion` field.

More information about this fix in this [thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/94421).

Comment: So what is the workaround to upgrade the kubeadm cluster? passing the version as argument also doesn't work

Comment: @MuhaiminAiman [As a best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), that's a different inquiry that requires you to post a new question in Stack Overflow. Ismael already stated it's a known bug.